# How to successfully "donate a book" as a function within a class

Tags: function, class, python-3.x, try-except

Let's say I have this virtual E-library and I have a function defined under a class that allows me to check if a book is in a given library BY ID NUMBER OF THE BOOK (which is an object) and if it isn't, I append it to the library. If I test it in a try-except block I keep getting the except message even though I know the ID number doesn't already exist. If someone can help me figure out this problem that would be good.

```
 class Library:
    # the class constructor
    def __init__(self, books, patrons):
        self.books=books
        self.patrons=patrons
    def __str__(self):
        s="Patron("
        for patron in self.patrons:
            s+=str(patron) + ', '
        if len(self.patron) != 0:
            s= s[:-2]
        s+=']'
        for book in self.books:
            s+=str(book) + ', '
        if len(self.books) != 0:
            s= s[:-2]
        s+='])'
        return s
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    def donate_book(self, book):
        for i in self.books:
            if i==book.book_id:
                raise DuplicateIdError()
            else:
                Library.append(book)
```

This is my try-except block:

```
        try:
            donate_book(book)
            print("Thank you for your Donation!")
        except:
            print ("that id# is already taken, sorry")
```

my library was defined as an empty list
library=[]
is my try-except block code wrong or is my donate_book code wrong?

my Book class:

```
 class Book:
    # the class constructor
    def __init__(self, author, title, book_id):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.book_id = book_id      
    def __str__(self):
        s = "Books("+self.author+", "+self.title+", "+self.book_id+")"
        return s
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

I defined duplicate error as this:

```
class DuplicateIdError(Exception):
#the class constructor
def __init__(self, ident):
    self.ident= ident
def __str__(self):
    s= print("'duplicate identificatoin: #" + self.ident + ".'")
    return s
    # returns a string rep matching 
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self)
```

Comment: Your error comes from the misplacement of the `else` clause in the `donate_book` method.

Comment: Change `donate_book(book)` to `<name of the library object>.donate_book(book)`. Another good tip would be to change  `except:` to `except DuplicateIdError:` because it's catching a `NameError` as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to use:

`if i.book_id == book.book_id:`

in your `donate_book()` method.

Comment: thanks for that but why is it that if i test it it always prints "that id# is already taken..." when I know it's not in the library

Comment: Can you post, your `Book` class implementation?

Comment: Can you also post your main method (the code you want to execute) and the error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your `donate_book` method like this:

```
def donate_book(self, book):
    if book in self.books:
        raise DuplicateIdError()
    else:
        self.books.append(book)
```

In the `Book` class, define this method:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.book_id == other.book_id
```

This **overrides the equality test** between books.

Comment: what I don't understand is that I still don't get the output I'm supposed to be getting. should I define library as something else?

Comment: `lib = Library([], [])`

Comment: Then, call the method like this: `lib.donate_book(Book('Slaughterhouse V', 'Kurt Vonnegut', 1234))`